# Как записать в String правильно функции и текст

Tags: c++, строки, оптимизация, arduino

Нужно запись несколько данных в строку. Но компилятор ругается. Если поставить String`("File Not Found\n\n")` в начале и убрать в других места.

Вопрос как правильно и красиво можно передать значения в строку?

```
String message =   "File Not Found\n\n"
                   "URI: " + (String)(HTTP.uri()) + "\n"
                   "Method: " + (String)((HTTP.method() == HTTP_GET)?"GET":"POST") + "\n"
                   "Arguments: " + (String)(HTTP.args()) + "\n";
```

Comment: В заголовке вопроса у вас `string`, в теле - `String`?

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, исправил. Везде String.

Comment: Между строками нужны знаки `+`.
А чтобы красивше выглядело можно использовать `StringBuilder`

Comment: Что это еще за `String`? Вы случаем язык не перепутали?

Comment: Ну, если это какой-то самопальный `String`, то надо знать, что он умеет - откуда же нам об этом знать?...

Comment: @user7860670 это Arduino/C++

Comment: @ВладиславИзотов Хоть бы тег поставили, мы же не телепаты.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такой метод:

```
 String message = (String)"File Not Found\n\n" +
                   "URI: " + HTTP.uri() + "\n" +
                   "Method: " + (String)((HTTP.method() == HTTP_GET)?"GET":"POST") + "\n" +
                   "Arguments: " + HTTP.args() + "\n";
```